# Table dosent load data using ng-repeat

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Im loading data from php to a variable in angular js but the table dosent load the data and remains empty

```
       <script>
           var app = angular.module('clientesApp', []);
               app.controller('clientesController', function ($scope,$interval) {
               $scope.clientes =[];
               $scope.error = [];
               $scope.alertMsg=false;
               $scope.carregarClientes = function () {
                   $.getJSON(
                       "/abcaia/getclientes.php", {},
                       function (jsonData) {
                           $scope.clientes = jsonData;
                           console.log($scope.clientes);
                           $scope.applay;
                       });

               };



         });
       </script>
```

I added a button that calls the function of requesting data and the data loads after that, but i whant for it to load when the page loads

```
       <div ng-init="carregarClientes()">
         <button id="btnEnviaComent" class="btn btn-success btn-x" ng-click="carregarClientes()">
             Enviar
         </button>
         <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>id</th>
                 <th>info</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody ng-repeat = "c in clientes" >
               <td>{{c.idCliente}}</td>
               <td>{{c.info}}</td>
             </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

i had $scope.apply; insted of $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke `$scope.carregarClientes()` after the function declaration. You will get the same results as clicking the button.

Comment: i already tryed doing that already but it still doesn't load the table, i also added a ng-init to my function but still no result, thnx anyway

Comment: Remove the `ng-init`, I'll suggest you to avoid putting logic in your templates. It makes it harder to debug it. Another suggestion is to use component base design. Did you debug it on the browser?